# transfering all files from one storage to another exercise on throw/throws exceptions

Tags: java

I need to transfer all files in method `transferAll(Storage storageFrom, Storage storageTo)`, and I have class Storage with variable: File[] files

that's what I have: but it doesn't work correctly

```
public void transferAll(Storage storageFrom, Storage storageTo){
    for (File files:storageFrom.getFiles()){
        for (File files1:storageTo.getFiles()){
            if (files!=null) files=files1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi there. What's the error / exception / stack trace ?

Comment: mentor told me that this isn't correct and i just wanted to find out what's wrong with it

Comment: check my updated answer

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're trying to move files from orgins in storageFrom to destinations specified in storageTo, you can try this with java 8:

```
File[] origins = storageFrom.getFiles();
File[] dests = storageTo.getFiles();

        if (origins.length != dests.length) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Origins and destinations do not match!");
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < origins.length; i++) {
            Files.move(origins[i].toPath(), dests[i].toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
        }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: yes, almost works but i can't use Files.move(origins[i].toPath(), dests[i].toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);

Comment: Why not? Are you using java < 8 ?

Comment: java 12 and im not allowed to import libraries

Comment: i think, i need just assign files of 1st storage to another\